# Android application not showing my location in map, error: could not find 'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.parceablegeofence'

Tags: android, location, maps, android-support-library

My android application is not showing my location on the map, but everything else is working fine and I have tried all the other solutions from other posts and google.
The locate button is showing but nothing happens when I click it and I don't know how to get the exception.

This is my code:

```java
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap myMap;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            initilizeMap();
            myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            myMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (myMap == null) {
            myMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            if (myMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Map not created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }
```

This is my androidmanifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.none"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="HIDDEN" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my activity main xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.none.MainActivity" >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Seleccione el punto clave" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what logcat shows me:
Could not find 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
Could not find 'ovw', referenced from method oyf.a
Could not fin class 'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.parceablegeofence', referenced from method gls.a

Comment: see [Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence referenced from method glt.a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626180/could-not-find-class-com-google-android-gms-location-internal-parcelablegeofenc)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it! just needed to implement a LocationListener to the MainActivity and its methods. Tell me if you need some code as answer.