# Android: NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzy(Ljava/lang/Object;

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebaseui

I create an app in which I can access in two waves: FirebaseUI Auth and Firebase SDK Authentication (I know that's quite wrong, I made this only for some tests). Well, from when I add the google access, I can't access with SDK Authentication, the app always crashes and I don't know why.
Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
DialogProgress dialogProgress;
EditText editEmail;
EditText editPassword;
String email;
String password;
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
final int REQUEST_CODE_GOOGLE = 100;
static Activity activity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    activity = this;
    editEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailA);
    editPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPasswordA);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bentornato " + firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ProfileActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    findViewById(R.id.accediButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            email = editEmail.getText().toString();
            password = editPassword.getText().toString();

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Email vuota",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Password vuota",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if(!(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)||TextUtils.isEmpty(password)))
            {
                DialogProgress.setLayout(0);
                dialogProgress = new DialogProgress();
                dialogProgress.setCancelable(false);
                dialogProgress.show(getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(),"Dialog");

                firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
                    {
                        if (task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            dialogProgress.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bentornato " + firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ProfileActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dialogProgress.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login fallito " + task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.registratiText).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,RegistrazioneActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.accediGoogle).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            AuthUI authUi = AuthUI.getInstance();
            Intent intent = authUi.createSignInIntentBuilder().build();
            startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE_GOOGLE);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int codice, int risultato, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(codice, risultato, data);
    if(codice==REQUEST_CODE_GOOGLE && risultato==RESULT_OK && data!=null)
    {
        IdpResponse idpResponse = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),idpResponse + "",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

Here is my gradle Project:

```
buildscript 
{
  repositories 
  {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies 
  {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
  }
}

allprojects 
{
  repositories 
  {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) 
{
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is my gradle app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android 
{
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
  defaultConfig 
  {
    applicationId "com.example.utente.myfirebase"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
buildTypes 
{
  release 
  {
  minifyEnabled false
  proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-
  rules.pro'
  }
}
}

dependencies 
{
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.4.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Log:

```
04-15 21:34:06.318 26912-26912/com.example.utente.myfirebase A/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.
                                                                        java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1737)
                                                                            at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1712)
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5437)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5032)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4972)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1491)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzy(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzab; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzab' appears in /data/app/com.example.utente.myfirebase-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes33.dex)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzx.zzdo(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source) 
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
                                                                            at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1737) 
                                                                            at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1712) 
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5437) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5032) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4972) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1491) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After upgrading to google play services 8.4.0 my app crashes on startup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34478757/after-upgrading-to-google-play-services-8-4-0-my-app-crashes-on-startup)

Comment: Can you post your stack trace?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice but It is very different

Comment: @Drew I have done

Comment: Please explain how your question is different.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it's conceptually different, in my case it didn't work with the access

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must use compatible versions of the Firebase API libraries and Firebase UI. The table of compatible version is in the [Firebase UI documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android). Change 9.4.0 to 10.2.0 for the `com.google.firebase:firebase-*` libraries.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Comment: I don't use Firebase. I use Onesignal which uses Firebase and I get the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Tina: Post a new question and include your build.gradle.  See also this: https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/issues/286

Comment: I just did post an answer with the whole detail :)       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49645215/onesignal-and-google-gms-incompatibility

Answer (score 6):

Change this:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.4.0'
```

To this:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.0'
```

You need to upgrade Firebase, you are using an old version. You will see Firebase has version 10.2.1 available, but according to `FirebaseUi` it currently supports Firebase version up to 10.2.0, so use 10.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

1. As it's mentioned here Update all the versions to the **latest ones** and all the **versions should be the same**.
2. Clean and Rebuild your Project

Run the project.

Answer (score 0):

Check comparability version of firebase, recommanded to use latest

In my case I have forgot to add below dependency

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
```

My all dependency  as below

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.1'
```

all use to send push notification to device